# Invalid date format issue in laravel for d/m/y format

Tags: php, laravel, date, validation

in my laravel application i have an input field to insert date of birth,

my date format has to be `d/m/y` and my age limit has to be 18-70

inside my controller's `store` method I have following validation rule for the dob.

```
'date_of_birth'=>['required','bail','date','date_format:d/m/y',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

                    $age=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
                    if($age<18||$age>70){
                        $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
                    }

                },]
```

but every time when I try to submit the form with a correct date like `23/12/1995` it kept saying date format is invalid

Comment: year in `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y')` should be uppercase `'d/m/Y'`

Comment: still not working

Comment: `'date_format:d/m/y` Y should be uppercase as well. It's because PHP uses uppercase Y as Year

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev try Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','10/10/1990')->diff(now())->format('%y') or arbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','10/10/1990')->diff(now())->y

Comment: @JohnLobo still invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two problems with your code:

1- you should remove 'date' from validation, since you are passing a string not  a date.

2- you should correct the format to be right: 'd/m/Y' Y is capital letter.

```
 $rules = ['date_of_birth' => ['required', 'bail', 'date_format:d/m/Y',

            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $age = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
            if ($age < 18 || $age > 70) {
                $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
            }

        },
            ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` method in function

```
$age=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
```

Comment: nope not working